# Bash Script not detecting failed exit codes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I can't get my bash script (a logging file) to detect any other exit code other than 0, so the count for failed commands isn't being incremented, but the successes is incremented regardless of whether the command failed or succeeded.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script for Homework 8
#Created by Greg Kendall on 5/10/2016
file=$$.cmd
signal() {
    rm -f $file
    echo
    echo "User Aborted by Control-C"
    exit
}
trap signal 2
i=0
success=0
fail=0
commands=0
read  -p "$(pwd)$" "command"
while [ "$command" != 'exit' ]
do
    $command
    ((i++))
    echo $i: "$command" >> $file
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
        then
            ((success++))
            ((commands++))
        else
            ((fail++))
            ((commands++))
    fi
    read -p "$(pwd)" "command"
done
if [ "$command" == 'exit' ]
    then
    rm -f $file
    echo commands:$commands "(successes:$success, failures:$fail)"
fi
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is why it's bad practice to check `$?` when you can just do `if $command; then ...` and observe exit status directly

Comment: that said, putting your command in a scalar variable is full of bugs too; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: also, `==` isn't a valid POSIX string comparison operator -- you're thinking of `=`. The former is supported as an extension in the test builtin provided by some common operating systems and shells, but it's not *guaranteed* to be present.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: That should be an answer! :)

Comment: ...btw, try running this whole thing through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: @l'L'l, eh, the only directly responsive thing I added is already covered in heemayl's answer; the rest is legitimately comments.

Comment: ...to echo what I said as a comment on heemayl's answer, btw -- it should almost certainly be `if eval "$command"; then`, not `if $command; then`. BashFAQ #50 covers the reasoning, and the bugs that follow from not doing this.

Comment: build youself a shell using better tool other than this, for instance, python cmd

Answer (score 3):

That's because `echo $i: "$command"` is succeeding always.

The exit status `$?` in `if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]` is actually the exit status of `echo`, the command that is run immediately before the checking.

So do the test immediate after the command:

```
$command
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
```

and use `echo` elsewhere

Or if you prefer you don't need the `$?` check at all, you can run the command and check status within `if` alone:

```
if $command; then .....; else ....; fi
```

If you do not want to get the STDOUT and STDERR:

```
if $command &>/dev/null; then .....; else ....; fi
```

** Note that, as [@Charles Duffy mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151955/bash-script-not-detecting-failed-exit-codes/37152002?noredirect=1#comment61841720_37152002) in the comment, [you should not run command(s) from variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: My only concern here is that echoing the OP's use of `$command` could be taken to endorse this as an acceptable practice. At barest minimum it should be `eval "$command"` -- that's not good practice, but at least it works (vs the current form, which fails w/ any command having quotes, backslashes, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correctly counting the number of times that the `echo $i: "$command"` command fails.  I presume that you would prefer to count the number of times that `$command` fails.  In that case, replace:

```
$command
((i++))
echo $i: "$command" >> $file
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
```

With:

```
$command
code=$?
((i++))
echo $i: "$command" >> $file
if [ "$code" -eq 0 ]
```

Since `$?` captures the exit code of the previous command, it should be placed immediately after the command whose code we want to capture.

#### Improvement

To make sure that the value of `$?` is captured before any other command is run, Charles Duffy suggests placing the assignment on the same line as the command like so:

```
$command; code=$?
((i++))
echo $i: "$command" >> $file
if [ "$code" -eq 0 ]
```

This should make it less likely that any future changes to the code would separate the command from the capture of the value of `$?`.

Comment: Thanks! Just a question though, why does using another variable in place of $? make a difference?

Comment: @GregKendall, what makes the difference is that the value of `$?` is being stored **immediately** after `$command` runs, so it's not being changed by your `(( i++ ))` or your `echo`.

Comment: BTW, I tend to suggest putting the capture on the same line as the command: `your_command; code=$?` -- that way other commands (like `echo`) won't be put between the command and capture by someone else adding debug logging or such and not looking too closely.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Excellent suggestion.  Answer updated with that change.

Comment: Good deal. btw, as I mentioned to heemayl, consider `eval "$command"` vs `$command` -- that way we aren't hitting bugs when the command contains quotes, backslashes, or likewise.